# Print out all permutations of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, permutation, factorial

I am working on a program, and I have a function that swaps the positions in an Array of length that is input by a user. However, I am trying to figure out how to print out this function call N! times, which would list all the permutations in the function.

My code for the permutation function is:

```
static void nextPerm(int[] A){
    for( int i = (n-1); i > 0; i-- ){
        if( A[i] < A[i+1] ){
            A[i] = pivot;
            continue;
        }
        if( A[i] >= A[i+1] ){
            reverseArray(A);
            return;
        }
    }

    for( int i = n; i > 0; i--){
        if( A[i] > pivot ){
            A[i] = successor;
            continue;
        }
    }

    Swap(pivot, successor);

    int[] B = new int[pivot+1];
    reverseArray(B);

    return;
}
```

Should I write a loop in function main, that will print this out n! times?

Comment: Sample input: Enter Length of Array: 5

Comment: Output: (1, 3, 5, 2, 4)
(1, 4, 2, 5, 3)
(2, 4, 1, 3, 5)
(2, 5, 3, 1, 4)
(3, 1, 4, 2, 5)
(3, 5, 2, 4, 1)
(4, 1, 3, 5, 2)
(4, 2, 5, 3, 1)
(5, 2, 4, 1, 3)
(5, 3, 1, 4, 2)

Comment: That is the hidden meaning of this piece of code: `int[] B = new int[pivot+1]; reverseArray(B);`? This reverses the zeroed array, doesn't it??? `reverseArray(A)` - this also looks strange... I suggest you to use the implementation from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30389456/2266855) instead, I tested it well, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Creating (or printing) the permutations of an array is much easier done as a combination of recursively and iteratively than purely iteratively. There are surely iterative ways to do it, but it is particularly simple with a combination. Specifically, note that there are by definition N! permutations of a length N array - N choices for the first slot, N-1 choices for the 2nd, etc etc. So, we can break an algorithm down into two steps *for each index i in the array*.

1. Select an element in the sub-array `arr[i....end]` to be the `ith` element of the array. Swap that element with the element currently at `arr[i]`.
2. Recursively permute `arr[i+1...end]`.

We note that this will run in O(N!), as on the 1st call N sub calls will be made, each of which will make N-1 sub calls, etc etc. Moreover, every element will end up being in every position, and so long as only swaps are made no element will ever be duplicated.

```
public static void permute(int[] arr){
    permuteHelper(arr, 0);
}

private static void permuteHelper(int[] arr, int index){
    if(index >= arr.length - 1){ //If we are at the last element - nothing left to permute
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        //Print the array
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
        }
        if(arr.length > 0) 
            System.out.print(arr[arr.length - 1]);
        System.out.println("]");
        return;
    }

    for(int i = index; i < arr.length; i++){ //For each index in the sub array arr[index...end]

        //Swap the elements at indices index and i
        int t = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = t;

        //Recurse on the sub array arr[index+1...end]
        permuteHelper(arr, index+1);

        //Swap the elements back
        t = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = t;
    }
}
```

Sample input, output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    permute(new int[]{1,2,3,4});
}

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 3, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 4]
[3, 2, 4, 1]
[3, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 1, 4, 2]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 3, 1]
[4, 2, 1, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 1, 2]
[4, 1, 3, 2]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without using the package java.utl.Arrays

Comment: It doesn't use util.arrays...

Comment: My function can only have parameters Int[] A

Comment: 1) Replaced Arrays.toString(..) with the by-hand version. It's literally the same thing, just doing it out.
2) The permute function *does* only have parameter a single parameter of type `int[]`. Is creating helper functions off limits?

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

I have followed this method most of the time .. (it's given by the Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne. ).

```
public class Permutations {

    // print N! permutation of the characters of the string s (in order)
    public  static void perm1(String s) { perm1("", s); }
    private static void perm1(String prefix, String s) {
        int N = s.length();
        if (N == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
               perm1(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, N));
        }

    }

    // print N! permutation of the elements of array a (not in order)
    public static void perm2(String s) {
       int N = s.length();
       char[] a = new char[N];
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
           a[i] = s.charAt(i);
       perm2(a, N);
    }

    private static void perm2(char[] a, int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println(a);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            swap(a, i, n-1);
            perm2(a, n-1);
            swap(a, i, n-1);
        }
    }  

    // swap the characters at indices i and j
    private static void swap(char[] a, int i, int j) {
        char c;
        c = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = c;
    }
```

However There is also an easier way to do this. May be you can work also around this

```
class PermutingArray {
    static void permutingArray(java.util.List<Integer> arrayList, int element) {
        for (int i = element; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            java.util.Collections.swap(arrayList, i, element);
            permutingArray(arrayList, element + 1);
            java.util.Collections.swap(arrayList, element, i);
        }
        if (element == arrayList.size() - 1) {
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arrayList.toArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PermutingArray
                .permutingArray(java.util.Arrays.asList(9, 8, 7, 6, 4), 0);
    }
}
```

Working Example here ..
[IDeone Link](http://ideone.com/g8BCgP)

Comment: The second solution is so compact! Shows how good you are at Java API usage.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to return a special value (`false` in the code below) from `nextPerm` when it was the last permutation (i.e. when array become sorted in descending order):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static boolean nextPerm(List<Integer> a) {
        int i = a.size() - 2;
        while (i >= 0 && a.get(i) >= a.get(i + 1))
            i--;

        if (i < 0)
            return false;

        int j = a.size() - 1;
        while (a.get(i) >= a.get(j))
            j--;

        Collections.swap(a, i, j);
        Collections.reverse(a.subList(i + 1, a.size()));
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

Then you can use the loop (note that the array required be sorted in ascending order initially):

```
    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4});
        do {
            System.out.println(a);
        } while (nextPerm(a));
    }
}
```

You can try this code here: http://ideone.com/URDFsc